# Is there a way to globally define a type in typescript? Interested in using bluebird instead of ES6 Promise

Tags: typescript

I'm a TS beginner. I see that if I compile my typescript code with `--target es6`, it knows the `Promise` type globally.

I want to use bluebird instead, and have a global `Promise` type be represented by bluebird. How do I accomplish this?

Specifically, I just want to avoid importing bluebird everywhere `Promise<T>` is mentioned.

Comment: Perhaps it's enough to just include a typings file for bluebird? "bluebird.d.ts"

Comment: I had it, but I didn't know what the `--global` flag in typings does, now I do :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Typings](https://github.com/typings/typings)

```
npm install typings
typings install dt~bluebird --global --save
```

Make sure your tsconfig.json and typings folder are in the same directory.

Comment: I have this in my `typings/index.d.ts` - `/// <reference path="modules/bluebird/index.d.ts" />`

Comment: but I haven't tried to actually import it anywhere, because I don't want to import it _everywhere_.

Comment: oh. I see, I had it in modules and not in globals, I moved it to globals and it somehow defined a global `Promise`. This is black magic.

Comment: Glad you figured it out before I came back :)

Answer (score 1):

Compile to target es5; include a custom global.d.ts in your tsconfig with something like:

```
declare var Promise: PromiseConstructor;

interface PromiseConstructor {
  new <T>(...)
}
```

You can check the definition of ES6 Promises automatically included by typescript in lib.es6.d.ts

Comment: This `global.d.ts` seems like the magic trick to creating global types, but is there a way to plug the existing bluebird definition here somehow? I have a bluebird typings definition already included in my project, how can I just plug it in? I read a very similar discussion [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/4112) but it's very cryptic and I don't understand how to actually accomplish it.